# Enabling mageplaza/module-smtp on Docker is not kept after docker restart

Tags: magento2.3, mageplaza

On a working Magento2 (2.3.1) Docker, I am enabling the module mageplaza/module-smtp :

```
magento module:enable  --clear-static-content Mageplaza_Smtp
```

After that, the module is in the enabled modules list :

```
magento module:status
```

When I restart the Docker, the image is no longer enabled, after restart the module is in the disabled modules list.
So I guess that some files are modified but not kept, because I am missing a persistent volume.

Here are the persistent volumes already created :

1. /pub/static
2. /generated
3. /pub/media
4. /var

Can anyone tell me the directory that is missing in my persistent volumes please ?

Comment: this change is actually saved in `app/etc/config.php` make sure your this file is saved

Comment: What cache engine are you using?

Comment: @WaqarAli thanks, it was a problem with app/etc/config.php, I put it in a persistent volume and now it's working like a charm, thanks a lot

Comment: Enjoy coding, Have a good Day!